# Display Image on particular size without compress and get image with particular size

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have problem with image dimensions.
when i have upload image with 500*500 dimensions or other, In this case i want 1024*768 dimensions Image output without compress. means, other space are automatic added (as a black background or other) on image background.
How can do i, any suggest for that.

1st i have try to display image on image control with fixed size.

.aspx

```
<asp:Image ID="ImagePreview1" BorderColor="Aqua" 
      BorderWidth="1px" runat="server"  Height="768px" Width="1024px" />
```

then click on button save image for particular folder..

.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = ImagePreview1.ImageUrl;
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(filepath, Server.MapPath("~/imgprev/pic.jpg"));
    }

}
```

In between i have also working with this code. This code for compress image size..

```
System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
            var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
            var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
            thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);
            thumbGraph.DrawImage(fullSizeImg, imageRectangle);
            string targetPath = imagePath.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "-resize");
            string SName = Path.GetFileName(targetPath);
            string SImgName = ("~/imgprev/") + SName;
            //string st = targetPath.ToString();
            //string stArr = st.Split('\\')[8];        

            thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); //(A generic error occurred in GDI+) Error occur here !
            Label1.Text = SImgName.ToString();

            thumbnailImg.Dispose();
            return targetPath;
```

Comment: Can you write what you've tried so far ?

Comment: i have add some code.